# Working with Datatables and RevealJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, reveal.js

The first issue I’m having is that I tried to format my code to be clean and easy to read but when I did and went through the sides  in my browser it didn’t format and made it misaligned so I worked with it to make it look aligned by then in the actual HTML file it looks unprofessional and hard to read. Why is this happening?

The second issue I’m having is with the actual data tables plugin itself is that when I have the HTML table to display the table rendered with the plugin it cuts a lot off and I tried applying a class to the table and modifying the height and width of the table but its not adjusting per my css rules.

And the last issue I’m having is that with my table HTML of the table to explain how it should be written it applies an ID to the table that shouldn’t be done until after rendering. Not sure why this is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Introduction of Datatables</title>
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="Creating a project to introduce the use of the Datatables jQuery plugin.">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/league.css" id="theme">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/zenburn.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

        <!-- Printing and PDF exports -->
        <script>
            var link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = window.location.search.match(/print-pdf/gi) ? 'css/print/pdf.css' : 'css/print/paper.css';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
        </script>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="lib/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>
            #table-container {
                width: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="reveal container-fluid">
            <div class="slides">

                <section>
                    <h1>Datatables</h1>

                    <p>jQuery Plugin for HTML tables</p>

                    <p>By: Me</p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <h2>Uses For Datatables</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Assists with paginating many rows of tabular data.</li>
                        <li>Can manipulate columns and rows via modifications with passed parameters</li>
                        <li>Can work with backend data via a API in the form of JSON</li>
                        <li>Can sort and search through data for results</li>
                        <li><strong>THEMEABLE</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <pre><code data-trim>
                        <table class="datatable table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Email Address</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>smorrow</td>
                                    <td>smorrow@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Owner</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>jstevens</td>
                                    <td>jstevens@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Editor</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>ksmith</td>
                                    <td>ksmith@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Basic User</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>wjones</td>
                                    <td>wjones@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Basic User</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>jcoonts</td>
                                    <td>jcoonts@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Administrator</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                    <td>rsimmons</td>
                                    <td>rsimmons@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Administrator</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </code></pre>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <h2>Javascript Code</h2>
                    <pre><code data-trim>
                        <script>
                        var dataTable = $('.datatable').dataTable();
                        </script>
                    </code></pre>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <div id="table-container">
                        <table class="datatable table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Email Address</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>smorrow</td>
                                    <td>smorrow@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Owner</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>jstevens</td>
                                    <td>jstevens@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Editor</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>ksmith</td>
                                    <td>ksmith@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Basic User</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>wjones</td>
                                    <td>wjones@example.com</td>
                                    <td>Basic User</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                        <td>jcoonts</td>
                                        <td>jcoonts@example.com</td>
                                        <td>Administrator</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td>rsimmons</td>
                                        <td>rsimmons@example.com</td>
                                        <td>Administrator</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/reveal.js"></script>

            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script>

            // Full list of configuration options available at:
            // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
            Reveal.initialize({
                controls: true,
                progress: true,
                history: true,
                center: true,
                viewDistance: 1,

                transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom

                // Optional reveal.js plugins
                dependencies: [
                {
                    src: 'lib/js/classList.js', condition: function () {
                    return !document.body.classList;
                }
            },
        {
            src: 'plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function () {
            return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
        }
        },
        {
            src: 'plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function () {
            return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
        }
        },
        {
            src: 'plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, condition: function () {
            return !!document.querySelector('pre code');
        }, callback: function () {
            hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
        }
        },
            {src: 'plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true}
            ]
        });
        </script>
        <script>
            var datatTable = $('.datatable').dataTable();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking at.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8luug2gsytnwno/Screenshot%202015-01-27%2012.50.43.png?dl=0

Comment: Try waiting for the document to finish loading before calling the dataTable plugin: $(function() { $('.datatable').dataTable() });

Comment: So I added that to section 3 and to the bottom of the document but still not getting anywhere.

Comment: What is getting cut off exactly?  Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: I don't because its on my localserver.

Comment: Here's a screen shot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8luug2gsytnwno/Screenshot%202015-01-27%2012.50.43.png?dl=0

Comment: it does not look like the data table is getting applied.  I noticed that the DataTable plugin is already applying the css class "dataTable".  I think your attachment of this class might be messing it up.  Rename the datatable class to something else and change your selectors, if you are only using it to select the tables.

Comment: `(function(){....})()` is all find and dandy. But its runs at read, not on ready. Even if you put it at the bottom of a script, it doesn't mean the DOM itself is loaded and ready with the elements you seek to manipulate. If your already working with jQuery just wrap the call to `$.datatable()` in a `$(document).ready(function(){});` statement